# The empty set as a subset

Tags: probability

What is the relevance of the part of the solution I have underlined in green in answering this question? We already know that the $\emptyset$ is a subset of any set already.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They want $P(A \mid B)$ to be defined, which requires $P(B) \neq 0$, which it seems they equate to $\emptyset \subsetneq B$, and notate as $\emptyset \subset B$. This notation is used in some places but not all authors use it. Note that the upper inclusion $B \subset \Omega$ is strict as well (with this notation) because you must also have $P(B') \neq 0$.

Note however that it may happen that $P(B) = 0$ even whilst $\emptyset \subsetneq B$.

Comment: I understand why $P(B)\neq 0$ but is the part of the solution relating to the empty set a necessary part of the solution or just some additional information?

Comment: @usainlightning if you do not have $P(B) \neq 0$ then $P(A \mid B)$ is *not even defined* and therefore, yes, it is needed for the solution.